# TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type while using boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have dataframe.

```
df=df.astype(np.float)
df.head()
x   y
1   0.6 2
0   1.1 1
3   3.4 4
2   4.3 3
```

And i am trying to generate a boxplot using it.

```
ax= plt.gca()
ax.boxplot(df[['x','y']])
```

But getting following error:
`TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

I am unable to understand why, as all of values in the dataframe are numbers.

Comment: Does `df` have 2 or 3 columns? [1,0,3,2] is just index?

Comment: it has only two columns

Comment: The error I have is: `NameError: name 'ax' is not defined`

Comment: @ipj because `ax = plt.gca()` must be used instead.

Comment: it was typo, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error is pretty explanarory. It can't handle its input which is a dataframe. Despite both dataframes and arrays has similar representation forms, they have an essential difference, that is, the output of `[n for n in df[['x','y']]]` is a list of column names (`['x','y']`) instead of column values. I guess you'd like values instead in your `boxplot` method so `df[['x','y']]` should be replaced with `df[['x','y']].values`.